# How to test cypress commands without running an entire test?

Tags: cypress

How can I test commands without running a test every single time?
In summary: I want a playground where I can test my commands before creating/running the tests.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I've found seems to work for click() and type().
It is not perfect, but at least it speeds up the development.

Create a simple test that you only enter the page you want to test:

```js
describe('My Tests', () => {
   it.only('My Playground', () => {
      cy.visit('#/page-i-want-to-test');
   });
});
```

Run your test with `cypress open`
After your test ran, it will be waiting on the last page.
Now it is the time that you can test your commands.

Open the dev tools > console and type: `Cypress.$`
This variable works like cy, but the root is the selector.

```js
 // this command
 cy.get('.button-wrapper').find('button').click();

 // becomes
 Cypress.$('.button-wrapper').find('button').click();
```

And that is all. Now you can test commands manually without having to wait for your entire suite to run.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a somewhat silly solution, but it works for me.

What I do is invoke the command at the beginning of the test I'm targeting, and after the command, I insert a long pause. For example, cy.wait(120000). This way, the test will not continue until the pause time has elapsed, and during that time, I check whatever I need to check in my command.

If you want to target a specific test, you can use "--spec [path to your test file]" and you can use "it.only" to target a specific test case within the file you are targeting.